# How to automatically init any classes in NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

Ok First Of all let me say, that What I am thinking of is to create attribute and use that Attribute to Automatically create instances of the classes decorated with that attribute. there is really to implementations of classes which can be constructed in my situation and I do not want to use IoC containers here because first I think they are not created till requested and second this is only for special set of classes which need to be auto instantiated and those are Service classes mainly. below is an implementation of the code used to create singleton

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator = 
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();

    private static readonly Lazy<T> Instance
        = new Lazy<T>(() =>
                          {
                              ConstructorInfo[] ctors = typeof(T).GetConstructors(
                                  BindingFlags.Instance
                                  | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                  | BindingFlags.Public);
                              if (ctors.Count() != 1)
                                  throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                      String.Format("Type {0} must have exactly one constructor.", typeof(T)));
                              ConstructorInfo ctor =
                                  ctors.SingleOrDefault(c => !c.GetParameters().Any() && c.IsPrivate);
                              if (ctor == null)
                                  throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                      String.Format(
                                          "The constructor for {0} must be private and take no parameters.",
                                          typeof(T)));
                              return (T)ctor.Invoke(null);
                          });

    public static T Current
    {
        get { return Instance.Value; }
    }
}
```

And here is a sample class which is defined as a singleton

```
public class PersonService : Singleton<PersonService>, IPersonService
{
    private PersonService()
    {
        RegisterForEvent<PersonRequest>(OnPersonRequered);
        //_serviceClient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICuratioCMSServiceClient>();
    }
}
```

Hwre Comes the Code used to resolve all types which needs to be activated.

```
public class InitOnLoad : Attribute
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        // get a list of types which are marked with the InitOnLoad attribute
        var types =
            from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            where t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InitOnLoad), false).Any()
            select t;

        // process each type to force initialize it
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            // try to find a static field which is of the same type as the declaring class
            var field =
                type.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
                               | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                               | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                               | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldType == type);
            // evaluate the static field if found
            //if (field != null) field.GetValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I found that fragment of the code on Stackoverflow and I think it is really interesting but did not managed to init classes.

Comment: Whats the problem with classes that are instantiated when requested? Wide use of singletons will bite you on the long term

Comment: Those are those are only service classes per module so this is not for whide use there will be minimum number of this type of classes.
the problem here is the Where close of firtordefualt method its criteria returns nothing

Comment: `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor`

Comment: Wow that sounds cool the only thing is that it takes argument of type tuntimehandler which and I see that for the very first time

Comment: Ok I think I managed to find the way but this makes my code to change
                RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);

Comment: The only problem here now is that when I moved that static constructor up to the base Singleton class all Services stopped working throwing exception  "The constructor for {0} must be private and take no parameters.", from line where it checks for if (ctor == null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static constructor to run code for a particular class before any reference to that class is made.  Here's some info from MS on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.100).aspx.

EDIT: [Jon Skeet has an article on this subject](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) that might answer your questions.  It also has code samples.

Comment: Yes But u must create instance of that type to activate static constructor first first time and as MSDN declares static constructor is declared only once before any instances are created, but this does not mean it will execute on its own without even referring to the instance

Comment: The static constructor is always executed, so there's a nice hook to startup your singletons

Comment: Can u have a look at the code and provide sample instance? I do not have problem creating singleton classes but only init them automatically and I tested static constructor and during execution there is no brake-point  hit inside static constructor.